# UWP Background Task is not executing

Tags: c#, uwp

I am new to uwp and I am trying to learn how to make a background task. I tried to follow the instruction I have found online but cannot seem to get it working. I am not getting an explicit error but my background task is not writing to the debug console. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

This is my main xaml
[image]

This is my mainpage class
[image]

This is my Background Task in the Windows Runtime Component Project("MyBackgroundTask")
[image]

This is my manifest
[image]

This is before I press the button
[image]

This is after I press the button
[image]

Comment: The background task probably runs under other instance of your code, not the one you're debugging. Also, it's scheduled by the OS to run periodically, isn't it? Can't you send  Windows notifications from it or write to some log file?

Comment: I cannot send notifications from it. I know my notification works because I tried it in the mainpage.xaml.cs and works there but not in background task. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, you are using [ApplicationTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn987023(v=win.10).aspx?appid=dev14idef1&l=en-us&k=k(windows.applicationmodel.background.applicationtrigger)%3bk(targetframeworkmoniker-.netcore,version%3dv5.0)%3bk(devlang-csharp)&rd=true) for your BackgroundTask. This will allow you to start executing your backgroundtask programmatically.

But you need to call [ApplicationTrigger.RequestAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn987029.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or [ApplicationTrigger.RequestAsync(ValueSet)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.background.applicationtrigger.requestasync.aspx) to start invoking your background task.

So, store your trigger globally, and call `trigger.RequestAsync` after registration(e.g. in another button click event handler) will solve the problem:

```
ApplicationTrigger trigger;
...
private async void btnTrigger_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await trigger.RequestAsync();
}
```